# Create hard-coded domains to autopopulate columns with aliases instead of codes in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, domain, vlookup, alias

I work with layer databases exported from ESRI ArcGIS Online. On ArcGIS, attribute tables have many columns (or fields) with codes. For each code corresponds a specific alias based on the properties of each columns. This is managed through hard-coded domains which automatically convert code numbers into aliases.
Unfortunately ArcGIS online is not able to export data to Excel preserving the aliases, thus returning me a database full of codes that cannot be interpreted without knowing the aliases beforehand.

The data I export from ArcGIS Online has at least one column that contains identificative numbers or codes for each entry. This "primary key" is what I use to repopulate the database in another Excel file using the VLOOKUP function only for the information I need from the source database exported from ArcGIS, allowing also the automatic update of data by overwriting the source database every time I need.

Suppose I have a column with information of the "Approval Status" and this column has 3 possible values, according to its ArcGIS domain codification.

As far as I know, I'm using two ways to manually or semi-automatically populate columns with aliases:

1. The easiest and most time-consuming way is to manually `Find and Replace` each code with the respective alias, for example:

Replace `1` with `"Accepted"`;

Replace `2` with `"Rejected"`;

Replace `3` with `"Resubmit"`;

2. The semi-automatic way is to implement the `VLOOKUP` formula that retrieves the data from the source file (Export.xlsx) with an `IFS` statement, by assigning for each code, its alias as `value-if-true`, as following:

   =IFS(VLOOKUP($A2,[Export.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$CV,11,FALSE)=1,"Accepted",VLOOKUP($A2,[Export.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$CV,11,FALSE)=2,"Rejected",VLOOKUP($A2,[Export.xlsx]Sheet1!$B:$CV,11,FALSE)=3,"Resubmit")

My problem is that the second way is heavy computing when the domain contains tens of codes and it has to be done every time the source database is different.

I also tried to use Coleptica, an Excel add-in with declared functionalities on code lists, but the official documentation states that this is a forthcoming feature.

Is there any way, in case also with VBA, to create "hardcoded" lists to automatically populate data with aliases based on each column properties?

Comment: Does it have to be done in Excel? This sounds like it'd be easier to handle in Python or similar, having a script to process the exports in batch (outputting an Excel file or CSV to continue working with).

Comment: @user1686 That would be a good alternative I can look into, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a VBA macro that will contain the
[Range.Replace method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace)
commands to replace values in columns, and run it once on any
new Excel file that you receive.

For example some (untested) code :

```
Sub replace_codes()
  Columns("A").Replace What:="1", Replacement:="Accepted", LookAt=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At first I thought the Columns("A") was just a reference and replaced the 'A' with the actual name of the column, but it didn't work, so it's necessary to declare the column as its letter code instead of its header